# Get a single value from a table with no ID with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am developing a web bot that scrapes the importation taxes from different countries customs website, and I have a problem retrieving the value I want from the following site : http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/itarancel/arancelS01Alias , using the test value 3303000000 next to CODIGO. The value I want to retrieve is the 6% next to "Ad / Valorem", but the table it is in has no ID properties nor class or something relevant to get directly to it or at least near to it. I have been trying to use .parent and .child methods, but without success. My code so far is as follows:

```
Function Peru(partida As String) As String

'Open IE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/itarancel/arancelS01Alias"

'Load sub
Cargar

'Navigate further into the website (Im using partida = 3303000000)
For Each box In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If box.Name = "cod_partida" Then
        box.Value = partida
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each boton In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If boton.Value = "Consultar" Then
        boton.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'Get the 6% value (This part is the one I cant figure out)

End Function
```

Comment: To reach the content you are after, you have to hurdle with two `iframes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the data from that page. It was needed to switch two `iframes` from that page to reach the required content.

```
Sub Aduanet_Info()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, frm As Object, frm1 As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/itarancel/arancelS01Alias"
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    html.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "3303000000"
    html.getElementsByTagName("input")(3).Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Set frm = html.getElementsByClassName("autoHeight")(0).contentWindow.document
    Set frm1 = frm.getElementsByClassName("autoHeight")(1).contentWindow.document

    For Each elem In frm1.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If InStr(elem.innerText, "Valorem") > 0 Then MsgBox elem.NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText: Exit For
    Next elem

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

```
6%
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code worked perfectly. I was just reading about iFrames now and just understanded why anything I tried did not work.